# How to prove Con(PA) in ZFC?

Tags: lo.logic

PA doesn't prove Con(PA) but ZFC does. That means the extra axiom of infinity is of tantamount importance in the proof. Not seen such a proof, think it would be interesting. Heard of it.

Comment: ZFC proves that the natural numbers (which exist by the axiom of infinity) are a model of PA, and therefore by soundness that PA is consistent?

Comment: Is this a research-level question?

Comment: Vote to close since this is too elementary a question for MO.

Comment: Wikipedia's article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity has a good explanation of how ZF proves that there is a set $\omega$ and an operation $S$ obeying the Peano axioms. In other words, ZF proves that there is a model of PA. (continued...)

Comment: This no doubt reveals my ignorance of set theory, but it seems to me to be a little tricky to finish from here. I would like a theorem of ZF saying "For any theory T, if T has a model then Con(T)". It's not  clear to me that this claim can be expressed in ZF! Everytime I try, I wind up wanting a truth predicate http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/TarskisResultOnTheUndefinabilityOfTruth.html . (continued)

Comment: For any finitely axiomatizable theory T, the claim "If T has a model then Con(T)" is expressible in ZF, and I see no obstacle to converting the obvious proof into a proof in ZF. But I don't quite see how to express this claim for a theory with an axiom schema, like PA. Experts, help?

Comment: I'm not voting to reopen this yet, but I've started a meta thread about it. http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/863/how-to-prove-conpa-in-zfc/

Answer (score 8):

Within ZFC you can formalize Tarski's definition of truth, then prove that the axioms of PA are all true and that the rules of inference preserve truth.  This gives a formal proof of Con(PA).

This allows you to prove not just the consistency of PA, but the consistency of PA + Con(PA),
or PA + Con(PA) + Con(PA+Con(PA)), etc.  Nothing close to the full strength of ZFC is needed for any of this (though of course you need *something* beyond PA).

Comment: @Steven : Small typo in the first line: The second ZFC should be PA.

Comment: Andres:  Thanks.  I went to edit this, but it looks like Terry Tao did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove the consistency of PA with second order logic.

The key thing is that you need a higher order induction hypothesis. In first order logic + PA, the induction hypothesis are limited to first order expressions.

The strength of a logic is often determined by what you allow in the induction hypothesis.